# Passing Child Id to Parent Function Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to pass child modal to my parent function. I have used this [Modal](https://github.com/dougludlow/ng2-bs3-modal)

**app.html**

```
<div class="head"><button class="headbtn" (click)="Popup(modal)">Add</button></div>
<div>
    <div class="centerDiv text-center" *ngFor="let hero of list">
      <div>
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash operation"></button>
        <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil operation" (click)="Popup(modal)"></button>
      </div>
      <div><h4>{{hero.Name}}</h4></div>
   </div>
</div>
<custom-modal></custom-modal>
```

**customModal.html**

```
<modal #modal> <---- this Modal 
<modal-header [show-close]="true">
    <h4 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h4>
</modal-header>
<modal-body>
    Hello World!
</modal-body>
<modal-footer [show-default-buttons]="true"></modal-footer>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

   list = [{ "Name": "App 1" }];

    Popup(modal) { <---  I am getting this modal undefined.
      debugger;
       modal.open();
    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**CustomModalComponent**

```
@ViewChild('modal') public modal: ModalComponent;
```

**app.html**

```
(click)="Popup(customModal.modal)"
...
<custom-modal #customModal></custom-modal>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/e2ST3HlkUMJPZAvtoYKH?p=preview)**

See also

- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html